# How do i match two values from 1 column in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Situation. CS-Cart has the following structure for options/variations tables. 
**[variant_options]** table has a **[combination]** column. 
**[combination]** stores the **[option_id]** and **[variant_id]** as 
**[option_id]** underscore **[variant_id]** i.e. 1_2, 1_3...

To match the correct option and it's variant to each product i need to be able to reference those values. i.e. LEFT JOIN variant_name ON variant_name.variantid = (the value after the underscore in the combination column.)

How would i do this? Thanks

Comment: and optionid = (the value before the underscore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    combination c
LEFT JOIN
        option o
ON      o.id = SUBSTRING_INDEX(c.combination, '_', 1)
LEFT JOIN
        variant v
ON      v.id = SUBSTRING_INDEX(c.combination, '_', -1)
```

Comment: awesome! works a treat. it did just get more complicated though. if i add more options to the product the combination string extends to become, option#_variation#_option#_variation# etc.(1_1_2_4). Any further ideas?

Comment: @jason3w: please post it as another question

Comment: done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753611/how-do-i-join-based-on-values-in-a-delimited-string-in-mysql