# How do i JOIN based on values in a delimited string in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Following on from previous question. [How do i match two values from 1 column in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752601/how-do-i-match-two-values-from-1-column-in-mysql)

**[variant_options]** table has a **[combination]** column. 
**[combination]** stores the **[option_id]** and **[variant_id]** as 
**[option_id]** underscore **[variant_id]** i.e. 1_2, 1_3...
 
To match the correct option and it's variant to each product i need to be able to reference those values. i.e. LEFT JOIN variant_name ON variant_name.variantid = (the value after the underscore in the combination column.)

Further to this, if multiple [options] are assigned to the one product, the string increases to become. 
optionid#_variationid#_optionid#_variationid# etc. (1_1_3_2)

Any further ideas appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't normalize your schema?

Comment: sorry i have no idea what that means. i am working with a database from an established cart. i am simply trying to extract a list of products with available options from the database.

Comment: this means that instead of stuffing everything into one column, you should create a mapping table: `(product_id, variant_id, option_id)` and put each option-variant pair into its own record (and its own field too)

Comment: hell yeah i'm with you on that one! only i can't change what they have built. just try and work out a way to get the info out. Product variations are pretty complicated. there's like 5 tables handling them.

Comment: or are you saying i can do that independent of their system? Make a table, and then fill it with those three values by somehow extracting that info from that delimited string?